# How to get FTP file path in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ftp

If I have user FTP account details like host name, username, password etc.

So How can get select file path from FTP server?

GUI:

1: User only click on button then open his/her FTP account automatically.

2: then user select any file from FTP server.

3: then How can I get FTP file name and path using angularjs?

Can I do this? Please suggest me. I appreciate all response. Thanks ahead.

Comment: There's no way to do exactly what you've asked without some kind of custom auth module on your FTP site or giving up on security completely. The only way to log in to a standard FTP server using a password is to put the password in the URL, which can end up in browser history and can be tracked by browser plugins and the browser itself. It's a bad idea. A better approach would be to provide access to FTP over HTTPS, or just make the user enter the password.

Comment: Thank you LinuxDisciple. How to access FTP over HTTPS using PHP?

Comment: You would write PHP that logs in to the FTP server, retrieves the information you want over FTP (the contents of a specific directory or a specified file) and then uses that to construct a webpage. There are lots of ready-built implementations of this though. Check out Monsta, net2ftp, etc.